# How to create AWS resources in multiple regions using for loop

Tags: terraform

I'm trying to launch AWS Config and rules in each region in my account. Right now in my root main.tf I create an AWS provider in a single region and call my AWS Config module from my modules directory. This is fine for creating one module, but I would be hoping to have a regions list that I could iterate over to create AWS Config rules in each

I have tried creating individual modules with region as a parameter, but I do not know if 10+ different modules is effective. It seems using a for loop would be more effective, but I cant find any examples for this behavior.

```
provider "aws" {
  region  = "${var.aws_region}"
}

module "config" {
  source          = "./modules/config"
  ...
}
```

My goal is to use my config modules over all and create them in all regions. us-east-1, us-east-2, us-west1-, etc etc

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're trying to dynamically pass in a list of regions to a module's provider in order to provision resources across regions in a single module. This is not possible at the moment.

Here is the ticket to upvote and follow: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/24476